# Chrome extension injected content not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am currently working on building a chrome extension using manifest v3. All the main files are configured and working but I seem to be running into problems with my injected content.

This is the basic structure of my injected content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="chrome-extension://[YOUR_EXTENSION_ID]/extension_bar.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="extension-bar">
    <header>
      <div class="logo">Your Logo</div>
      <div class="extension-icons">
        <img src="chrome-extension://[YOUR_EXTENSION_ID]/close-icon.png" id="close-icon" alt="Close">
      </div>
    </header>
    <p id="extension-message">Message</p>
  </div>
  <script src="chrome-extension://[YOUR_EXTENSION_ID]/extension_bar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It injects correctly when a user loads a page with a specific URL structure. The problem is with the "close-icon". I simply want the user to close the extension bar when clicking this X icon.

I tried this code in extension_bar.js in various forms:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // Get the URL of extension_bar.js using chrome.runtime.getURL()
  const extensionBarScriptUrl = chrome.runtime.getURL('extension_bar.js');

  // Get the URL of extension_bar.css using chrome.runtime.getURL()
  const extensionBarCssUrl = chrome.runtime.getURL('extension_bar.css');

  // Function to remove the injected content when close-icon is clicked
  function closeExtensionBar() {
    const extensionBar = document.getElementById('extension-bar');
    extensionBar.remove();
  }

  // Add event listener to close-icon
  const closeIcon = document.getElementById('close-icon');
  if (closeIcon) {
    closeIcon.addEventListener('click', closeExtensionBar);
  }
});
```

When I try clicking the icon nothing happens.

Comment: For a complex UI it's best to inject it inside an iframe. Your content script will add an iframe and point its src to an html file exposed via web_accessible_resources. The file will load scripts directly, i.e. without chrome-extension:// prefix, just like you would do it in the action popup page.